# What exactly does soc.recv return?

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, python-3.x, byte

According to the python documentation, python's socket recv() method returns an array of 'byte' types.

However, if you print out this array, things that don't look like bytes also appear:

```
\xd9\x01\x01\xa4\xe9\xcbV6\x15\xed|>g5\xfa\xbd\xe9Q\x19@i\x18\xff\
```

Does the python byte object have some internal error reporting or something?  What are these byte objects that don't appear to be actual bytes being returned?

Some more odd examples:

```
\x00w\xd4\x04;\x9c\x0b}>P]\xa4\xbd\xa5n:9x\xe3>9\xd2/~8\

\x01\x01\x1b ,Y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf4

\xa0A\n\xd7tB}\xed,\xc0\x00\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv` dose indeed return raw bytes. It's only in the printing that Python bytes assumes an ASCII encoding, if the value falls within the values that are ASCII printable it will print it as the ASCII character represented by that 8bit value. If not an ASCII printable it escapes the value with `\x` and prints the hex.

Note that if you are using python 3.5 you can call `.hex` on the bytes above and see what the hex values are. This should confirm you are getting the values you expect.

Feel free to verify that the values you send are what you expect by using Wireshark or similar, it's only in the printing that you will see this.

Comment: So the byte object itself (as in, not printing it) will have proper values even if they aren't within the ASCII encoding, correct?

Comment: Yes, if the value is not ASCII printable it just gives you the hex value `\x`. If you see what actually goes over the wire in something like Wireshark you will see that the values are what you expect. This is merely an artifact of how python prints these.

Comment: Alright, thanks much.  Hopefully the rest of the logic will work properly then!

Comment: Also note that if you are using python >3.5 you can call `.hex()` as a method directly on the bytes and you will see the hex representation. Might be useful for your verification efforts here.